# Not able to migrate, Foreignkey in models is causing the issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

so I have the two following models that I'm trying to migrate.

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=STATUS,default='active')
logo_file_path = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
```

and

```
class Team(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=STATUS,default='active')
org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisation(),to_field=id, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
I need Team.org_id linked to Organisation.id, so I'm trying to use it as a foreign key.
```

but while trying to make migration it is giving me the following system error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:

db_app.Team.org_id: (fields.E312) The to_field 'db_app.Team.id' doesn't exist on the related model 'db_app.Organisation'.
```

Note: db_app is my django app name.

I guess the `to_field` argument in the foreign key is causing the issue. I'm not sure though.

I have tried it on different models in a different project the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,to_field=id, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or

```
 org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And also the Organization class is created above the Team class

Comment: Later one worked.